# Running Idea Mergetool

Tags: git, intellij-idea, mergetool, difftool

I have inside my `.gitconfig`

```
[merge]
    tool = intellij
[mergetool "intellij"]
    cmd = /usr/local/bin/idea merge $(cd $(dirname "$LOCAL") && pwd)/$(basename "$LOCAL") $(cd $(dirname "$REMOTE") && pwd)/$(basename "$REMOTE") $(cd $(dirname "$BASE") && pwd)/$(basename "$BASE") $(cd $(dirname "$MERGED") && pwd)/$(basename "$MERGED")
    trustExitCode = true
```

so I can run `git mergetool` and get Intellij IDEA's mergetool.

The problem with this is since we are executing from `/usr/local/bin/idea` requires admin privileges. However, if I run `sudo git mergetool` IDEA would run this time, but as sudo, causing all the files changed to have changed permissions, in particular, changing the ownership of the file. Further it does not load user-specific config when running as sudo.

What would be the solution?

Comment: Do you run git commands from the command line or inside IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1):

> executing from /usr/local/bin/idea requires admin privileges

Typical permissions of executables in `/usr/local/bin` are `755`, which means anyone can run executables from there. (checked on Mac and Ubuntu 18/04 - permissions are the same).

Looks like something is misconfigured on the system so that running ide wrapper requires sudo.

Check and adjust permissions /usr/local/bin/idea accordingly.